# Build App in Release mode, but use DEV config

Tags: android, .net, azure-pipelines, maui

We have the following code in our azure pipelines:

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: 'APPNAME/APPNAME.Android.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--configuration ${{ variables.buildConfiguration }} -o $(build.binariesdirectory) -f net7.0-android'
    modifyOutputPath: true
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

We have 3 environments and in the App.xaml.cs in the project we have the following:

```
#if DEBUG || DEV
    public const string Environment = "dev";
#elif QA
    public const string Environment = "qa";
#else
    public const string Environment = "live";
#endif
```

The code then picks different config files depending on which environment is being used. All this works fine locally.

When we do a publish in the pipeline for the DEV version, an apk file is produced but it cannot be uploaded to the play store because the "APK is marked as debuggable." I'm guessing this is because the I haven't got -c Release in the arguments, but doing this will cause the code to select the config files for the live environment.

What I am trying to do is build the Dev/QA version of the app, but build it in release mode so the debuggable flag is false, but use the Dev config files in project.

Comment: just set the DEV symbol in the config for Release mode

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more please?

Answer (score 1):

first, you can define whatever Configurations you want.  These are completely arbitrary.

[image]

next, for each configuration, you can define a set of Compiler symbols to use.  Again, these are completely arbitrary.  If you want to add the DEV symbol to the Release config, go ahead.  If you want to create symbol named WOMBAT nothing is stopping you.

[image]

finally, you can enable/disable debugging per configuration.  There is nothing preventing your from enabling debugging in your Release config

[image]

Comment: I have the Developer Instrumentation turned off my DEV config, but the apk is still marked as debuggable when published in the pipelines

Comment: also check the Debug section in the Compiler tab, and verify that the DEBUG symbol is not set for that config

Comment: My Visual Studio doesn't have the Complier tab in the project properties for whatever reason, but I did a search in the csproj file and couldn't find anything related